# Styling react-alice-carousel dots

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a react carousel added to one of my components. Here is the code:

```
<div className={styles.carouselContainer}>
                    <AliceCarousel
                        mouseTracking
                        disableButtonsControls={true}
                        responsive={{
                            0: {
                                items: 2,
                            },
                            1024: {
                                items: 3,
                            },
                        }}
                    >
                        {icons.map(icon => (
                            <Image
                                src={`${mainsite}/${icon.src}`}
                                width={78}
                                height={48}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </AliceCarousel>
</div>
```

I am using css modules rather than pure css as shown in my `div`.

How can I style the carousel dots since I can't access css selectors the same way I would if I weren't using css modules?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question might be old, but I found myself in the same situation and I solved it by overwritting the react-alice-carousel css classes.

Alice-Carousel uses `.alice-carousel__dots-item` css class to style the inactive dots, and `.alice-carousel__dots-item.__active` class for the active dots. So, by overwritting them you can style the dots

carousel.css:

```css
.alice-carousel__dots-item.__active{
    background: #782bc6 !important;
}

.alice-carousel__dots-item {
    background: #9134ee57 !important;
}
```

Import the css into the component

carousel.js:

```js
import "./carousel.css";
import AliceCarousel from "react-alice-carousel";

export const Carousel = () => {
  const items = [
    <div className="item" data-value="1">
      1
    </div>,
    <div className="item" data-value="2">
      2
    </div>,
    <div className="item" data-value="3">
      3
    </div>,
    <div className="item" data-value="4">
      4
    </div>,
    <div className="item" data-value="5">
      5
    </div>
  ];

  return (
    <AliceCarousel
      mouseTracking
      items={items}
      responsive={{
        0: {
          items: 2
        },
        1024: {
          items: 3
        }
      }}
    ></AliceCarousel>
  );
};
```

Here the link to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-alice-carousel-styling-jd9t06?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Use this and style the component ArrowL and ArrowR according to your need:

```
renderPrevButton={( )=>{return <ArrowL/>}}
renderNextButton={( )=>{return <ArrowR/>}}
```